# How can I iterate through a sub TreeMap in Java?

Tags: java, iteration, treemap

How do I iterate through the sub-TreeMap?

Java gives an error at the second `for` cycle, at `_entry.getValue().entrySet()`, without any indication of the nature of the mistake I have in my code.

```
for (Entry<Integer, TreeMap> _entry : propertiesList.entrySet()) {
    for (Entry<Integer, TreeMap> _rowEntry : _entry.getValue().entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you at least show us the error?

Comment: What is the full type of `propertiesList`?  It's very unclear what you're trying to do, especially with the raw `TreeMap` in the type of `_entry`.

Comment: The propertiesList is defined like: TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap> propertiesList = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap>();

Comment: @GáborDani: What are the entries in the sub map like?  It should be a `TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Foo, Bar>>` for some `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first TreeMap is not a generic TreeMap. You should have something like:

```
TreeMap <Integer, TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap>> propertiesList = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap>> ();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap>> _entry : propertiesList.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, TreeMap> _rowEntry : _entry.getValue().entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

This will fix it.